# I get the ClassCastException error when filling in the user class

Tags: java, android

I get the ClassCastException error when filling in the user class.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to com.projects.chatroom_2020.UserClient

joinChatroom class

```
  DocumentReference joinChatroomRef = mDb
            .collection(getString(R.string.collection_chatrooms))
            .document(mChatroom.getChatroom_id())
            .collection(getString(R.string.collection_chatroom_user_list))
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());


    User user = ((UserClient) (getApplicationContext())).getUser();
    joinChatroomRef.set(user);
```

UserClient class:

```
public class UserClient extends Activity {

private User user = null;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

Comment: You're casting applicationContext to UserClient ! why? where are you using joinChatroom? you need to somehow reach a reference of the User object to joinChatroom

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` will return the context of the calling activity. So if you're calling it outside of `UserClient` it will throw an exception. You could instead create a singleton for `UserClient` in order to call it's methods externally.